# How to configure this router?

Tags: networking

i've the following configuration:

1. A: Internet Gateway/Router . All my PC's are connected to it. IP: 192.168.1.254
2. B: switch/Router DD-WRT connected to A. Internet Gateway configured to out to A. In this switch there's configured a PPTP Vpn. I use to connect only a single device to it (so it go out via VPN).
   IP: 192.168.1.1

All works correctly (i can surf either via Router A and B, if connected to it)

The problem: i would like to use my main PC (connected via cable to router A) to connect via browser to 192.168.1.1 .. the problem is that router B don't answer, i think for a loop problem. 
So i have to physically disconnect cable to router A and connect it to router B. Then, it answer!

**In your opinion, can i connect to router B from a PC connected physically to router A ?**

Thanks

EDIT: An important note: pinging 192.168.1.1 from a PC (with a gateway setted to 192.168.1.254) i've no answer...

Comment: `i would like to use my main PC (connected via cable to router A) to connect via browser to 192.168.1.1` I assume that 192.168.1.1 is running web-server right?

Comment: Yes, dd-wrt at 192.168.1.1 has a web server

Comment: Oh, so that is the IP of your router? If you can’t ping the router, then something is wrong with it. Have you tried pushing the reset button? Have you tried doing a factory reset (holding the reset button for ~30 seconds)?

Comment: Synetech, yes, always done. It is a configuration problem...

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine.

The issue here is that from Router B's perspective, 192.168.1.1 is the WAN link (meaning it is the side of the router that is facing the internet).  By default, all access to UI/administrative functions will be blocked in the firewall for requests coming in on the WAN link.

Adjust your firewall settings to allow access to the admin website on the WAN interface for the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.  Alternatively, you could put your main PC on a static IP and just allow access for that single IP.

Note that there may be a few different settings you need to look for.  For example, most firmware has a setting called "block private networks" in the firewall. With this on, the router will see traffic coming to the WAN link from the Class C block (192.168.1.0/24) and drop it by default, even though in your case this is legit network traffic.

Comment: No, it not working! I've enabled "allow remote web administration" but ..not work!